# html checkbox switch active/inactive labels not working

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am using the switch class from foundation-zurb and I am using the example from their website, but the inside labels for the inactive/active settings are not working. The code is below:

```
<p>Above/Below</p>
<div class="switch">
    <input class="switch-input" id="Above/Below" type="checkbox" name="ABSwitch">
    <label class="switch-paddle" for="Above/Below">
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">A</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">B</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

The A and B on the respective active/inactive settings of the switch do not show up.

Comment: Could it be because of the browser you are testing it with ?

Comment: I am using safari. It has never not worked for any php/html or curb-foundation classes. But maybe that could be? I'll check with another browser.

Comment: nope it doesn't work on chrome either :/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.1.1/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<p>Above/Below</p>
<div class="switch">
    <input class="switch-input" id="Above/Below" type="checkbox" name="ABSwitch">
    <label class="switch-paddle" for="Above/Below">
        <span class="switch-active" aria-hidden="true">A</span>
        <span class="switch-inactive" aria-hidden="true">B</span>
    </label>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.1.1/js/foundation.accordion.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).foundation();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```